# Drag out file into HTML5 File Upload Dropzone

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, fileapi

There's a method by which you can drag files out of Chrome to your local file system. It's detailed here and works well: http://www.thecssninja.com/demo/gmail_dragout/

I have a HTML5 File Upload widget that I'd like to be able to drag a file into, one that's hosted on my server and a reference to which is embedded in the page.

The drag in doesn't seem to get a file in the event.dataTransfer list of files.

Is this possible to do?